# Why is there only ".sp" in fontSize of Text("") composable and not ".dp" in Jetpack Compose-beta08

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I want the size of the text to be in `.dp` so that it doesn't change according to the system font.
How to achieve this in Jetpack Compose "Text" composable

Comment: `so that it doesnt change according to the system font. ` doesn't sound very user friendly. what if i can't read your font size ?

Comment: The `fontSize` works with a `TextUnit`. It can accept `sp` and `em`

Comment: I just wanted to keep a consistent font size for my bottom navigation bar labels. Just used ```em``` and it worked.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Compose team does not intend to provide that possibility, `em` are a bit pita to use, but there is an easy workaround should anyone really need it.

```
@Composable
fun dpToSp(dp: Dp) = with(LocalDensity.current) { dp.toSp() }

Text("ABCD", fontSize = dpToSp(15.dp))
```

Taken from the same issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/190644747.

Comment: I was the one who asked that on issue tracker but forgot to update that answer here in stackoverflow; thank you for providing the code :D

Comment: it is not easy to handle the interface when the user increases or decreases the font size. So this option is also somewhat reasonable. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use extension properties：

```
private fun Int.textDp(density: Density): TextUnit = with(density) {
    this@textDp.dp.toSp()
}


val Int.textDp: TextUnit
    @Composable get() =  this.textDp(density = LocalDensity.current)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Stable
val Int.tdp: TextUnit @Composable get() = textDp()

@Stable
val Double.tdp: TextUnit @Composable get() = textDp()

@Composable
private fun Int.textDp() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@textDp.dp.toSp() }

@Composable
private fun Double.textDp() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@textDp.dp.toSp() }
```

Use:

```
Text(
        text = "My Text",
        fontSize = 22.tdp,
        color = Color.White
    )
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you [edit] your answer to add details and explain how it works and why it fix the issue from OP?