# Prevent system font scaling - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, font-scaling

I am trying to restric the app from affected fro system font scaling. I had gone through many solutions but none helped. Most of them tell use dp instead of sp for text sizes but in compose we can use only sp if i am right as it expects a Text Unit.
Is there any right way to restrict font scaling in our app done with jetpack compose ? Please help .

(Solutions refered) : https://l.workplace.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F21546805%2Fhow-to-prevent-system-font-size-changing-effects-to-android-application&h=AT0zIuBPbUONm0T6q8PtqbxCdX6P_ywlp-yFGrqPMqZt7H3wsWYltKO5XwbW3i0lenrxxLi3nn_kMO4aPtFUfig2iG0BcRZpd0wTuZ1_XFpdsjDM6E7RPyZ-G_c2dlmuzGqsSEHYbqBJun0hLLZgOpRUszKbe9-1xQ

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918698/why-is-there-only-sp-in-fontsize-of-text-composable-and-not-dp-in-jetp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918698/why-is-there-only-sp-in-fontsize-of-text-composable-and-not-dp-in-jetp)

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69112444/3585796

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have an extension for `Int` or `Float` like this

```
@Composable
fun Int.scaledSp(): TextUnit {
    val value: Int = this
    return with(LocalDensity.current) {
        val fontScale = this.fontScale
        val textSize =  value / fontScale
        textSize.sp
  }
```

You can add an extension parameter of Int

```
val Int.scaledSp:TextUnit
    @Composable get() =  scaledSp()

Text(text = "Hello World", fontSize = 20.scaledSp)
```

Comment: Could you please give an example to implement this to text?

Comment: @RezaFaraji `Text(text = "Hello World", fontSize = 20.scaledSp())`

Answer (score 3):

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    val newOverride = Configuration(newBase?.resources?.configuration)
    if (newOverride.fontScale >= 1.1f)
        newOverride.fontScale = 1.1f
    applyOverrideConfiguration(newOverride)
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
}
```

You can use something like this in your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Till there is no solution on jetpack compose for `Text()`, you can use AndroidView:

```
@Composable
fun CustomText(
// attributes you need to set
){

     AndroidView(factory = { context ->
                    AppCompatTextView(context).apply {
                        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25)
                        setText("")
                        // other attributes you want to set or other features which is not available in jetpack compose now.
                    }
                },)

}
```